# Probability of guessing a 4 digit pin on a public entry point?

Tags: probability

So my son's daycare has changed their entry method from an RFID card to a 4-digit pin.  To open the door, you have to enter a 4 digit pin (you choose your pin, it is not assigned).  There is no other metric tying the pin to the person.  This is the only entry verification.  Once you enter a correct pin at the main door, you have access to the entire building, there are no other doors or security within the building.  You don't even have to walk by a person (ie reception).

What is the probability of getting into the building by guessing a random 4 digit code?

I know I need to get more information:

- Number of pin's
- Are the pins unique?
- Are they filtering out dumb ones (ie 1234)
- How many wrong attempts do I get?
- Anything else I should ask?  If so, how will that affect things?

I would like to meet with them to discuss my concerns.  Could someone help with the math so I can factor in the above as I get the information?  I will probably create a spreadsheet and put in the numbers as i'm having the meeting.

Am I overthinking this?  [Damn it Jim,] I'm an engineer not a mathematician, but my gut tells me it is insecure...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are $10000$ possible PINs, between $0000$ and $9999$. Assuming there are $100$ PINs assigned to $100$ different people, guessing one of those PINs is a $1$ in $100$ chance. Assuming you get $3$ tries, your chance of getting at least one try correct is $1 - (99/100)^3 \approx 3\%$. This is already an uncomfortably high chance, in my opinion.

Comment: How can we answer?  Do the digits of the PIN have to be distinct?  Many of the numeric pads I have seen require that.  Does the order they are entered matter?  Some pads just make sure you have the right set of four numbers.  In that case there are only ${10 \choose 4}=210$ codes.  Usually for this kind of thing everybody gets the same PIN, which should be changed every time somebody leaves.  How can we know if they filter out dumb ones?

Comment: You should suggest they have one PIN and make everyone enter that one. This reduces the chances of guessing correctly in three tries to $1-(9999/10000)^3 =0.02\%$. Having different PINs for different people that all open the door makes it much, much more likely that a randomly guessed PIN will match.

Comment: @kccu Your point is correct, but the above calculation is not. If you have three attempts, the probability of guessing a single, random PIN equals $\frac{3}{10^4} = 0.03%$.

Comment: @jvdhooft Good point, since you will change your guess in the event that you are wrong. But you should have $0.03\%$, not $0.03$. Slightly higher than what I said in my original comment, but still much lower than if there are $100$ different correct PINs. (Perhaps you typed a % sign and MathJax hid it. You need to type \% for it to show up.)

Comment: @kccu Apparently, the percentage sign was not properly generated. Indeed, your general conclusions are definitely valid!

Comment: Thanks all, i'll try to answer everything:
@RossMillikan I will be asking them these questions when I meet with them.  Sorry for not being more clear.

Comment: So really what this comes down to is I have to guess someones pin.  The odds come down to how many unique pins there are.  If there are 200, I have a 1/200 chance to guess each time.  So having one pin would be more secure from a numbers standpoint, but maybe not a human standpoint (ie someone lets it slip what the pin is...)

Comment: The more unique pins they have, the higher the chances someone has to guess a pin right?  How do I figure out the % chance go guess right after three tries with N number of pins in the system?  is it just @LukasKofler equation subbing in the number of pins?  1-((N-1)/N)^3 ?

Comment: I think that someone guessing the code is probably not a big concern, especially if there is any mechanism that reacts to having $n$ consecutive incorrect attempts. Even a 10-second waiting period between attempts would be hugely helpful; you might ask if such a thing exists as well. One relative *strength* of this over an RFID approach is that you can't accidentally drop the code on your way out of the building, unlike an RFID card. However, a relative weakness is that a nefarious actor could watch over someone's shoulder or look for fingerprints on the keypad.

Comment: Note also that having someone disclose the PIN to a bad actor isn't any worse if there's just one master PIN than if there are several. In fact, I think it's better to have just one PIN, because then that PIN can be changed if it is breached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fleshed out in the comments, but I'll write this in the spirit of contributing an answer to this question.

This is one of those probability problems where it's easier to consider the chances of something *not* happening than having it happen. Suppose there are $N$ possible codes, of which $k$ work (hence, $N-k$ don't work). If a nefarious actor guesses by entering codes randomly, then the chance of getting the code *wrong* on the first try is $(N-k)/N$; hence, the chance of getting it *right* on the first try is $ 1- \frac{N-k}{N} = k/N$.

If they get to try a second time, then they're probably smart enough to discard their first wrong answer. There are still $k$ working codes, but there is now one less incorrect code to try, and one less code overall to consider. Thus, their chances of getting the code wrong twice are $\frac{N-k}{N} \cdot \frac{N-k-1}{N-1}$, and their chances of getting the code right at least once in their first two attempts is $1 - \frac{N-k}{N} \cdot \frac{N-k-1}{N-1}$.

You can hopefully see how this generalizes at this point. If they get $r$ tries at the code, then the probability of not opening the door becomes
$$\frac{(N-k)(N-k-1) \cdots (N-k-r+1)}{(N)(N-1) \cdots(N-r+1)}$$
and thus the probability of them opening the door somewhere before that is the above subtracted from 1. If we wanted to express this compactly, we could use factorial notation; the probability of opening the door within the first $r$ attempts would be
$$1 - \frac{(N-k)!/(N-k-r)!}{N!/(N-r)!}.$$

So, to make this more concrete: it is probably the case that any 4-digit number can be used as a code, and that the order of the digits matters, which would imply that $N = 10,000$ for this example. If we assume there are $k = 100$ valid codes, and the intruder can have $r = 3$ attempts, then the probability that they can get in is
$$1 - \frac{9900!/9897!}{10000!/9997!} \approx 3\%$$
as discussed in the comments. See [this link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%20-%20%5Cfrac%7B%28N-k%29%21%2F%28N-k-r%29%21%7D%7BN%21%2F%28N-r%29%21%7D%20where%20N%20%3D%2010000.0%2C%20k%20%3D%20100%2C%20r%20%3D%203) for a calculator that you can edit to reproduce these computations quickly.

Having only one code helps, but I'd argue the most important thing is probably to ensure that there's a practical cap on the number of attempts. If there are just five working codes but the user gets 100 tries at it, the probability of entry is almost 5%. (You can see this with the above link, or just by realizing that the intruder gets to try 100 different codes from among the 10,000 possible codes.) Notice that if something like a 10-second delay is placed between guesses, this would

As a fellow parent, I definitely share you concern about this situation, but (as I pointed out in the comments as well) there are advantages and disadvantages of this approach over an RFID card. A card could be dropped on the ground or stolen, which a PIN cannot. However, someone could disclose the PIN inappropriately, or a bad actor could watch over someone's shoulder, or they could use context clues like fingerprints or smudges to identify keys that are likely part of the code.

I find myself wondering if your *real* concern may not be with the PIN code, but rather the day care's commitment to security. If that's the problem, it won't be fixed by any security measure imaginable. You might ask them *why* they've made this switch. (Is it just for cost?) Have they carefully thought through the ramifications and risks of the switch? Are they able to articulate the relative strengths and weaknesses of the two methods? I think what you're looking for is evidence that anyone has put any thought into this.

My gut instinct is that a would-be bad guy is unlikely to sit there and guess codes for long, and that they would be more likely to try surveillance to obtain the code, entering through a window, or some other means of accessing the building. (I'm not an expert in security and have no real basis for that statement.) If the day care is flippant about security, then they could have a bank vault lock on the front door and it probably wouldn't stop a breach from happening.

So if it were me having a conversation with the day care about this, I'd ask them why they made this change, and I'd be looking not for some particular answer, but rather for them to have some convincing evidence that they've carefully considered this.

And man, it'd be nice if they had a receptionist.

Comment: Aaron, Thank you for the thorough response, it is greatly appreciated.  

I think you nailed it about the general concept of their security.  If someone really wanted to get in there and hurt the kids, there are so many easier ways (ie the playground fence could easily be hopped, although there are always at least two adults with the kids).  My concern was the switch to a pin and how it was implemented led me to believe no one with much real experience in security made the decision.

Comment: Also, I found out this morning that they didn't tie the code into the time system.  With the RFID, you couldn't enter the building until 7am (and I assume after 6pm).  This was a policy they put in place for the daycare.  I tried the code at 6:55 am and was able to get in.  This does not help how I feel about the root concern.  I will set up a meeting with them soon to discuss and see what other contingencies they have in place.  Thankyou again for all the help with the math.